# Responding to a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to send a message "E" to the channel where someone sent a message starting with s#. I have got 2 problems:

1. I have got a function:

```
function read(msg)
{
  if(msg[0] === "s" && msg[1] === "#") console.log("E");
}
```

and I don't know how to call this function with a message that someone sent as 'msg'.

2. And when I figure out how to do this, I would like to add a `channel.send("E");`, but I don't know how to get the id of the channel that the message was sent to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the read function there two ways

As @SickBoy Said,

```
function read(msg){
if(msg.content.startsWith('s#'){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

or else,

```
function read(msg){
const data = msg.content.split('')
if(data[0] === 's' && data[1] === '#'){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

To call this function simply add a event of message.

```
client.on('message' , message=> {
const res = read(message)
if(res){
//The message starts with s#
}
else{
//It doesn't start with s#
}
})
```

Comment: You can add anything you need if the condition is true.

Comment: ok, but how do i call the function everytime someone sends a message?

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('s#')) console.log('s#');//check if the message starts with s#
});
```

2. 

```js
message.channel.send('this is a reply to the message sent in this channel');
```

see docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message

**Edit (the whole code with the read function):**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    read(message);
});

function read(message){
   if(message.content.startsWith('s#')) console.log('s#');
}

client.login('your-token-here');
```

Comment: its not a problem, just pass the message.content as a parameter.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: thank you very much, but why not just ```client.on('message', read(message));```? i don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called `message` which gets emitted whenever someone sends a message in the server. This event returns a `message` object which contains all the information about that message like content, author, channel, member, etc. So to send something back as a reply you can do this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('s#')) {
        message.channel.send('E');
    }
}
```

Also, I saw you're doing this in your `ready` function: `msg[0]`. This is not how you access the content of a `message` object. It's not an array. You can get the content of a message using `let text = message.content`. This text is of string type and stores the message text.

Comment: ok, but for ```client.on('message', read(message.content));``` it says that message is not defined.